# yarn 2 how to publish workspace package from dist

Tags: yarn-v2

In a yarn 2 typescript monorepo setup, I have several workspaces under my `./packages/*` directories built to `./dist/` directory. Now I want to publish a few packages to my GitHub npm registry. However, running `yarn npm publish` only published my original (TypeScript) sources under `./packages/*` instead of the built `*.js` and `*.d.ts` under my `./dist/`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @pcben, have you found an answer/workaround?

Comment: @Murad No, we rushed into writing some lightweight scripts to do what we want instead -- I can't recall off the top of my head what exactly it was, I think we're still using yarn npm publish in their original paths instead of going through dist. We haven't had the time to research the proper way of doing this yet.